# How to pass a variable in through Xpath using Selenium through Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath

This Xpath works fine when i am passing static id  i.e

```
driver.findElementByXPath("//tr[@id='Billable Client']/td/input").getAttribute("id");
```

but It doesnt work when I passed variable i.e

```
String  Level3KeyCase0Trimmed = "Billable Client";
driver.findElementByXPath("//tr[@id='"+Level3KeyCase0Trimmed+"']/td/input").getAttribute("id");
```

tried by removing '...' single qoutes as well

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"?  What specific error do you get?

Comment: In addition to Simon's question, you need to post the code for `findElementByXPath()`. There may be something in there that is causing the problem. Have you tried adding a wait? It could just be a timing issue but it's hard to tell without the error message and more info.

Answer (score 0):

Within the *xpath*:

```
driver.findElementByXPath("//tr[@id='Billable Client']/td/input").getAttribute("id");
```

If you want the *value* of the `id` attribute to be a variable you can use the following solution:

```
String  Level3KeyCase0Trimmed = "Billable Client";
browser.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[@id='" + Level3KeyCase0Trimmed + "']/td/input")).getAttribute("id");
```

Comment: How is this any different than the code OP posted? Your XPath is exactly the same. The only thing you changed is `driver` to `browser` (with no explanation as to why and it won't make any difference) and `findElementByXPath` to `findElement` which isn't going to make any difference either.